# height: 100% for <div> inside <div> with display: table-cell

Tags: html, css, css-tables

Here is 2 column markup using `display: table` and `display: table-cell` CSS declarations:

```css
.table {
  display: table;
}

.cell {
  border: 2px solid black;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: table-cell;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="cell">
    <p>Text
      <p>Text
        <p>Text
          <p>Text
            <p>Text
              <p>Text
                <p>Text
                  <p>Text
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="container">Text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But `.container` block does not fill parent cell vertically. Here is an example on JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MGRdP/2.

**What I have** | **What I need**

[image: What I have] [image: What I need]

Please, do not propose JS solution.

Comment: The issue is that you are using `height: 100%;` for child element whose parent `height` is set to `auto`, so inorder to fix this, assign `height: 100%;` to all the parents, and if not, than use some fixed `height` for `.cell`

Comment: +1 for no JS solution.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

When you use `%` for setting heights or widths, always set the widths/heights of parent elements as well:

```css
.table {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
}

.cell {
    border: 2px solid black;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
}

.container {
    height: 100%;
    border: 2px solid green;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
    <div class="cell">
        <p>Text
        <p>Text
        <p>Text
        <p>Text
        <p>Text
        <p>Text
        <p>Text
        <p>Text
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        <div class="container">Text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should add `-moz-box-sizing: border-box;` to the `.container` to make it also work correctly on FF.

Comment: Yes you are right. the `.container` div was having a height greater than 100%. Fixed it and updated the jsfiddle in my answer

Comment: Change the table height to 1px and it works for IE11. Nothing below that though.

Comment: Why doesn't this work in <IE11 - this is ridiculous. It works on every single browser, mobile and otherwise - but IE .. I can't stand it. GAH

Comment: @JamesSouth any suggestions for IE9, 10?

Comment: @user1561346 Not of the top of my head I'm afraid.

Comment: Just wait a few more weeks and you won't have to worry about IE10 and below anymore :-) https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/WindowsForBusiness/End-of-IE-support

Comment: @Capsule Microsoft dropping support is so not equal to people stop using it.

Comment: @Growiel no but at least you can justify why they get a degraded version of your website

Comment: To add to what James South pointed out, adding `height: 100%; min-height: 1px;` to the `display: table` class will help IE 11.

Comment: interesting. it works in FF 57. need to do some more digging

Comment: This solution stopped working on Chrome unfortunately

Comment: These short answers has a tremendous power, sometime. Indeed, it works, at least on Firefox. Tks :)

Answer (score 57):

```
table{
   height:1px;
}

table > td{
   height:100%;
}

table > td > .inner{
   height:100%;
}
```

Confirmed working on:

- Chrome 60.0.3112.113, 63.0.3239.84
- Firefox 55.0.3, 57.0.1
- Internet Explorer 11

Comment: table { height:1px; } is the key

Comment: This one actually worked well with the new version of Chrome, after the accepted solution stopped working for it.

Comment: ridiculous, but perfect. Thanks! I actually didn't even need the `td { 100% }`, just the `table` and `.inner` styles worked for me.

Comment: But why? Is this a bug or intended behavior?

Works like a charm on firefox 68.5 and chrome 79.

@Scrimothy `td { 100% }` is still needed by firefox.

Comment: @KamilBęben I'd not noticed that on FF. Thanks

Comment: This is a hack, not a solution. May cause unintended behaviour in other ways.

Comment: This works better than the previous inexplicable HTML/CSS hack I found elsewhere on the internet: `td { height: 1px; }`

Answer (score 27):

set `height: 100%;` and `overflow:auto;` for div inside `.cell`

Comment: `overflow:auto;` was the key for me. Thanks!

Comment: But what about the scroll bar which appears with `overflow: auto` ?

Comment: Doesn't work for me

Answer (score 20):

In Addition to jsFiddle, I can offer an ugly hack if you wish in order to make it cross-browser (IE11, Chrome, Firefox).

Instead of `height:100%;`, put `height:1em;` on the `.cell`.

Comment: Can you explain why changing height: 100% to height: 1em; works?
1em should just be the height of the letter "m" .... Funny, I have a similar issue as above and changing to height:1em fixed my issue across the board.
Kudos!

NOTE* I did not do anything else like changing position etc...

Comment: I'm not sure if its ugly, but it works. Wish I knew why.

Comment: `height: 1px;` works for me. And in my opinion, this is better than setting it on the entire table as suggested in another answer.

Answer (score 11):

Make the the table-cell position relative, then make the inner div position absolute, with top/right/bottom/left all set to 0px.

```
.table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  position: relative;
}

.inner-div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: What if your `.inner-div` have margins or it can have overflowing content?

Answer (score 7):

This is exactly what you want:

**HTML**

```
<div class="table">

    <div class="cell">
        <p>Text</p>
        <p>Text</p>
        <p>Text</p>
        <p>Text</p>
        <p>Text</p>
        <p>Text</p>
        <p>Text</p>
        <p>Text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        <div class="container">Text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.table {
    display: table;
    height:auto;
}

.cell {
    border: 2px solid black; 
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:top;
}

.container {
    height: 100%;
    overflow:auto;
    border: 2px solid green;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: `-moz-box-sizing: border-box;` for `.container` is here for it :)

Comment: Works in FF, but not in IE (11)

Answer (score 4):

Define your `.table` and `.cell` `height:100%;`

```
    .table {
        display: table;
        height:100%;
    }

    .cell {
        border: 1px solid black;
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align:top;
height: 100%;

    }

    .container {
        height: 100%;
        border: 10px solid green;

    }
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MGRdP/5/)**

Comment: None of those solutions worked on Bootstrap elements: table element is a raw, cell element is a col-lg and the container is a panel