# Expand child div to heigh of table div parent

Tags: html, css

I know this "expanding child div to parent height"-thing is old and today we can solve things with flexbox and grids. But my problem is a bit different. I need the format of a table with dynamic width values, depending on there content. So each row should decide it's height and each column it's width based on there contents. Also the number of columns and rows is variable.

That's why I can't use flexbox or grid based layout. They are not dependent on each others width or height just of the height/width of there own children.

Also: the table has some other tags inside. Not just text!

Because of that I can't use a normal `<table>` tag. It's not allowed to use other html tags inside a table cell tag.

So I decided to use `<div>` tags and set them to tables via css.

```css
.table {
  background: #bbbb;
  display: table;
}

.table-row {
  display: table-row;
}

.table-cell {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: table-cell;
}

.content {
  background: #f005;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
    <div class="table-row">
        <div class="table-cell"><div class="content">1 / 1</div></div>
        <div class="table-cell"><div class="content">1 / 2</div></div>
        <div class="table-cell"><div class="content">1 / 3</div></div>
    </div>

    <div class="table-row">
        <div class="table-cell"><div class="content">2 / 1</div></div>
        <div class="table-cell">
            <div class="content">very long content <br /> with line break and all the stuff</div>
        </div>
        <div class="table-cell"><div class="content">2 / 3</div></div>
    </div>

    <div class="table-row">
        <div class="table-cell"><div class="content">Another very long <br /> line <br /> breaking <br /> content and ither <span>html tags</span></div></div>
        <div class="table-cell"><div class="content">3 / 2</div></div>
        <div class="table-cell"><div class="content">3 / 3</div></div>
    </div>
</div >
```

The challenge now is to expand all the `<div class="content">` tags to the full width and height of the parent/table-cell.

Note: I can't use flexbox here because `display:` is already used to show the div as a table cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `height:100%` to the content, table-cell and table

```css
.table {
  background: #bbbb;
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
}

.table-row {
  display: table-row;
}

.table-cell {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100%;
}

.content {
  background: #f005;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">
      <div class="content">1 / 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <div class="content">1 / 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <div class="content">1 / 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">
      <div class="content">2 / 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <div class="content">very long content <br /> with line break and all the stuff</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <div class="content">2 / 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">
      <div class="content">Another very long <br /> line <br /> breaking <br /> content and ither <span>html tags</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <div class="content">3 / 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <div class="content">3 / 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Related: [height: 100% for <div> inside <div> with display: table-cell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22220698/8620333)

Comment: Change it to `height:100%;` for the table-cell and it works. Nice. Thank you :)

Comment: @Tobi updated the code, it seems to behave differently with browsers. Now it should be the same everywhere

Answer (score 1):

Grid could also be an option and it would need less markup :

```css
.grid {
  background: #bbbb;
  display: grid
}

.c3 {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto)
}

.shrink {
  width: max-content;
  /* behave alike a table */
  margin: auto;
}

.content {
  border: solid 1px;
  background: #f005;
  padding:0.25em;
}

.grid~.grid .content {
  margin: 2px;
  /* mimic border-spacing*/
}
```

```html
<div class="grid c3 shrink">
  <!--<div class="table-row">  <div class="table-cell">-->
  <div class="content">1 / 1</div>
  <!--</div>
  <div class="table-cell">-->
  <div class="content">1 / 2</div>
  <!--</div>
  <div class="table-cell">-->
  <div class="content">1 / 3</div>
  <!--</div> </div> <div class="table-row">  <div class="table-cell">-->
  <div class="content">2 / 1</div>
  <!--</div>  <div class="table-cell">   -->
  <div class="content">very long content <br /> with line break and all the stuff</div>
  <!--</div>  <div class="table-cell">-->
  <div class="content">2 / 3</div>
  <!--</div> </div> <div class="table-row">  <div class="table-cell">-->
  <div class="content">Another very long <br /> line <br /> breaking <br /> content and ither <span>html tags</span></div>
  <!--</div>  <div class="table-cell">-->
  <div class="content">3 / 2</div>
  <!--</div>  <div class="table-cell">-->
  <div class="content">3 / 3</div>
  <!--</div> </div>-->
</div>

<hr>

<p>cleaned up html </p>
<div class="grid c3 shrink">

  <div class="content">1 / 1</div>
  <div class="content">1 / 2</div>
  <div class="content">1 / 3</div>

  <div class="content">2 / 1</div>
  <div class="content">very long content <br /> with line break and all the stuff</div>
  <div class="content">2 / 3</div>

  <div class="content">Another very long <br /> line <br /> breaking <br /> content and ither <span>html tags</span></div>
  <div class="content">3 / 2</div>
  <div class="content">3 / 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You answer works, but you have to define the number of columns in the css. So if the user adds a column to the table I have to rewrite the css. IMO this is a bigger pain then  generating longer markup on the client.

Comment: @Tobi here is where you need to update the column number : `grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto)`  in a class called c3 . make a class for each number , you can even use css(var) to shorten the code. demo with a click https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/ExPmwrV