# How to make a div inside a td to use 100% height

Tags: html, css

In this example I would like to make all the orange divs stretch out to the enclosing td element height, without the need to specify the parent's height. I tried `display: flex` along with `align-items: stretch` and various other combinations but I can't get the design I need. It looks so simple to achieve, but I think it requires deep knowledge of the CSS model, which unfortunately I lack.

[image: example]

```css
td {
  background-color: aliceblue;
}
```

```html
<table style="width: 800px;position: absolute;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>cell 1</td>
      <td>cell 2</td>
      <td>cell 3</td>
      <td rowspan="3">normal text in a td is using 100% height.</td>
      <td rowspan="3" style="height: 100%">
        <div style="background-color: orange;">a div with colspan inside a td is not using 100% height.</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>cell a</td>
      <td>cell b</td>
      <td>cell c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>cell x</td>
      <td>
        <div style="background-color: orange;">a div inside a td is not using 100% height.</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: lightgreen; padding: 8px">a large cell</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22220698/height-100-for-div-inside-div-with-display-table-cell) answer your question

Comment: Why dont you just put the background color on the td ?

Comment: @JiaSH I did not intend to modify the structure of the dom in this case

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to a comment I found this solution

```
<style>
    td {
        background-color: aliceblue;
    }
    table{
        height:1px;
    }

    .inner {
        height:100%;      
    }
</style>

<table style="width: 800px;position: absolute;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>cell 1</td>
            <td>cell 2</td>
            <td>cell 3</td>
            <td rowspan="3">normal text in a td is using 100% height.</td>
            <td rowspan="3" style="height: 100%">
                <div class="inner" style="background-color: orange;">a div with colspan inside a td is not using 100% height.</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>cell a</td>
            <td>cell b</td>
            <td>cell c</td>
            
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>cell x</td>
            <td><div class="inner"style="background-color: orange;">a div inside a td is not using 100% height.</div></td>
            <td><div class="inner" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: lightgreen; padding: 8px">a large cell</div></td>
            
        </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

This gives the desired solution

[image: solution]

I understand that the trick of giving a dummy height to the parent's table forces the css rules to kick in. A bit strange for me, but as long as it works it's okay.

Comment: Any reason for not just coloring background on the TD?

Comment: yes, in my case I wanted to have full control on the content being rendered in the TD. The background color was just an example to let me understand why the td's content are not 100%